# How can I reorder my divs using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Given a template where the HTML cannot be modified because of other requirements, how is it possible to display (rearrange) a `div` above another `div` when they are not in that order in the HTML? Both `div`s contain data that varies in height and width.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        Content to be below in this situation
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        Content to be above in this situation
    </div>
</div>
Other elements
```

Hopefully it is obvious that the desired result is:

```
Content to be above in this situation
Content to be below in this situation
Other elements
```

When the dimensions are fixed it easy to position them where needed, but I need some ideas for when the content is variable. For the sake of this scenario, please just consider the width to be 100% on both.

I am specifically looking for a CSS-only solution (and it will probably have to be met with other solutions if that doesn't pan out).

There are other elements following this. A good suggestion was mentioned given the limited scenario I demonstrated—given that it might be the best answer, but I am looking to also make sure elements following this aren't impacted.

Answer (score 339):

**A CSS-only solution** (works for [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)) – use Flexbox's `order` property:

```css
#flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#a { order: 2; }
#b { order: 1; }
#c { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div id="flex">
   <div id="a">2nd</div>
   <div id="b">1st</div>
   <div id="c">3rd</div>
</div>
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Ordering works here. But the children are not getting 100% width. Instead, they are sharing their spaces in the same row. Any idea how 100% width can be utilized for each child with this method?

Comment: `#flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` will display 100% width rows. http://jsfiddle.net/2fcj8s9e/

Comment: It can be done using `transform` with a wider browser suppport

Comment: Not supported on iPhone 6s and below

Comment: This solution allows you to choose any desired order for any number of divs.  This should be the accepted solution IMO.

Comment: This is a clean solution.

Comment: For me, any divs not ordered seem to be 0.  The two divs I wanted pinned to top I just `order:-1` and left the rest at default 0.

Answer (score 302):

[This solution](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/) uses only CSS and works with variable content

```css
#wrapper   { display: table; }
#firstDiv  { display: table-footer-group; }
#secondDiv { display: table-header-group; }
```

Comment: Nice! Doesn't work for IE8 or lower though but you could use a conditional script for those browsers...

Comment: It's true that is not working for IE7, but I have no problem with IE8

Comment: Yes this is very nice for mobile content reordering, and IE concern is out of the window!  Think menus that are defined first and appear on the left for normal layouts, but you want them to appear at the bottom on narrow mobile displays. This does the trick very nicely.

Comment: Should be noted that this does not work with floats. You have to set the float:none; if you already had a float set.

Comment: Great trick.  One thing I've found that doesn't work is rounded corners or the ability to specify a width.  As soon as I give the first dive "table-footer-group" as its display, I lose the ability to do this things.

Comment: Worked for me as well however, I needed to add `width:100%;` to the wrapper class.

Comment: Note: `img { max-width: 100% }` won't work inside the reordered elements.

Comment: Any obvious reason why this doesn't work straight away for me on a window resize using @media screen and ( max-width: 480px )? It only seems to work if I refresh the browser at the smaller width.

Comment: With these rules, the firstDiv and the secondDiv won't obey `width: 100%;` anymore(although their parent has not shrinked).

Answer (score 87):

As others have said, this isn't something you'd want to be doing in CSS. You can fudge it with absolute positioning and strange margins, but it's just not a robust solution. The best option in your case would be to turn to javascript. In jQuery, this is a very simple task:

```
$('#secondDiv').insertBefore('#firstDiv');
```

or more generically:

```
$('.swapMe').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).insertBefore($(el).prev());
});
```

Comment: Sometimes its best to yield to those more powerful. In this case this feels more elegant and you are in real control. For that reason I feel this is neater and better.

Comment: This may have been true around 2008, but unfortunately this answer is very out of date now.

Answer (score 40):

This can be done using Flexbox.

Create a container that applies both **display:flex** and **flex-flow:column-reverse**.

```css
/* -- Where the Magic Happens -- */

.container {
  
  /* Setup Flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  /* Reverse Column Order */
  -webkit-flex-flow: column-reverse;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;

}


/* -- Styling Only -- */

.container > div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container > div:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="first">

     first

  </div>
  
  <div class="second">

    second

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Sources:

- https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 26):

There is absolutely no way to achieve what you want through CSS alone while supporting pre-flexbox user agents ([mostly old IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)) -- **unless**:

1. You know the exact rendered height of each element (if so, you can absolutely position the content).  If you're dealing with dynamically generated content, you're out of luck.
2. You know the exact number of these elements there will be.  Again, if you need to do this for several chunks of content that are generated dynamically, you're out of luck, especially if there are more than three or so.

If the above are true then you can do what you want by absolutely positioning the elements --

```
#wrapper { position: relative; }
#firstDiv { position: absolute; height: 100px; top: 110px; }
#secondDiv { position: absolute; height: 100px; top: 0; }
```

Again, if you don't know the height want for at least #firstDiv, there's no way you can do  what you want via CSS alone.  If any of this content is dynamic, you will have to use javascript.

Comment: OK, I downvoted this too, first, but reverted. One bit of refinement is still due to the conditions, though: you do *not* need to know the *exact* number of elements to reorder, *unless* that number is > 3 (see the [bounty-winning answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069537/1479945)). This is relevant especially for OP specifically only wanted to swap 2 items.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution:

```
<style>
#firstDiv {
    position:absolute; top:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position:relative; 
}
```

But I suspect you have some content that follows the wrapper div...

Comment: Yes ... trying not to be too wordy with the situation, but there are other elements following. Good suggestion though given the limited HTML provided -- might work for someone else.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Flex

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#firstDiv {
  order: 1;
}

#secondDiv {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        Content to be below in this situation
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        Content to be above in this situation
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

With CSS3 flexbox layout module, you can order divs.

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#firstDiv {
  order: 2;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    Content1
  </div>
  <div id="secondDiv">
    Content2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend using `order: -1` if you want to make 1 element out of many "sticky" on top :)

Answer (score 7):

**If you just use css, you can use flex.**

```css
.price {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    flex-direction: row-reverse; //revert horizontally
    //flex-direction: column-reverse; revert vertically
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
      <div>first block</div>
      <div>second block</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know, or can enforce the size for the to-be-upper element, you could use

```
position : absolute;
```

In your css and give the divs their position.

otherwise javascript seems the only way to go:

```
fd = document.getElementById( 'firstDiv' );
sd = document.getElementById( 'secondDiv' );
fd.parentNode.removeChild( fd );
sd.parentNode.insertAfter( fd, sd );
```

or something similar.

edit: I just found this which might be useful: [w3 document css3 move-to](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-content-20030514/#move-to)

Answer (score 5):

Negative top margins can achieve this effect, but they would need to be customized for each page.  For instance, this markup...

```
<div class="product">
<h2>Greatest Product Ever</h2>
<p class="desc">This paragraph appears in the source code directly after the heading and will appear in the search results.</p>
<p class="sidenote">Note: This information appears in HTML after the product description appearing below.</p>
</div>
```

...and this CSS...

```
.product { width: 400px; }
.desc { margin-top: 5em; }
.sidenote { margin-top: -7em; }
```

...would allow you to pull the second paragraph above the first.

Of course, you'll have to manually tweak your CSS for different description lengths so that the intro paragraph jumps up the appropriate amount, but if you have limited control over the other parts and full control over markup and CSS then this might be an option.

Answer (score 5):

Ordering only for mobile and keep the native order for desktop:

// html

```
<div>
  <div class="gridInverseMobile1">First</div>
  <div class="gridInverseMobile1">Second</div>
</div>
```

// css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .gridInverseMobile1 {
    order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
  }
  .gridInverseMobile2 {
    order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Desktop: First | Second
Mobile: Second | First
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Answer (score 4):

In your CSS, float the first div by left or right. Float the second div by left or right same as first. Apply `clear: left` or `right` the same as the above two divs for the second div.

For example:

```
#firstDiv {
    float: left;
}

#secondDiv {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: <div class="container">
  <div id="secondDiv"><p>...</p></div>
  <div id="firstDiv"><p>...</p></div>
</div>

Comment: On my case float: right; clear: left; working perfect

Comment: using clear is great way, but note you should float your element in correct direction and also you should float all other elements to do correct.

Vestel you should use some styles like this:
<style>
#secondDiv, #firstDiv {
float: left;
}

#firstDiv {
clear: left;
}

</style>
<div class="container">container<div id="secondDiv"><p>secondDiv</p></div> <div id="firstDiv"><p>firstDiv</p></div> </div>

Answer (score 3):

Well, with a bit of absolute positioning and some dodgy margin setting, I can get close, but it's not perfect or pretty:

```css
#wrapper { position: relative; margin-top: 4em; }
#firstDiv { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; }
#secondDiv { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

The "margin-top: 4em" is the particularly nasty bit: this margin needs to be adjusted according to the amount of content in the firstDiv. Depending on your exact requirements, this might be possible, but I'm hoping anyway that someone might be able to build on this for a solid solution.

Eric's comment about JavaScript should probably be pursued.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with CSS only!

Please check my answer to this similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25462829/1077230

I don't want to double post my answer but the short of it is that the parent needs to become a flexbox element. Eg:

(only using the webkit vendor prefix here.)

```
#main {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Then, swap divs around by indicating their order with:

```
#main > div#one{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    overflow:visible;
}

#main > div#two{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a bigger browser support then the flexbox (works in IE≥9):

```css
#wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
#wrapper > * {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        Content to be below in this situation
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
        Content to be above in this situation
    </div>
</div>
Other elements
```

In contrast to the `display: table;` solution this solution works when `.wrapper` has any amount of children.

Comment: What if the div contains an image>?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to change the orders of the divs only for mobile version so then I can style it nicely. Thanks to nickf reply I got to make this piece of code which worked well for what I wanted, so i though of sharing it with you guys:

```
//  changing the order of the sidebar so it goes after the content for mobile versions
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 480 )
    {
        jQuery('#main-content').insertBefore('#sidebar');
    }
    if ( jQuery(window).width() > 480 )
    {
        jQuery('#sidebar').insertBefore('#main-content');
    }
    jQuery(window).height(); // New height
    jQuery(window).width(); // New width
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex for the parent div by specifying `display: flex` and `flex-direction : column`.
Then use order to determine which of the child div comes first

Comment: Why do you think this answer to 7y old question is better than those already posted? If you want to participate on SO, please find questions without (good) answers and try to anwer them in a fashion which will be helpful for all the visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse displaying order of children. I suggest you use this

> `direction: rtl;`  // Right to left

Set this property in parent element

Answer (score -1):

CSS really shouldn't be used to restructure the HTML backend. However, it is possible if you know the height of both elements involved and are feeling hackish. Also, text selection will be messed up when going between the divs, but that's because the HTML and CSS order are opposite.

```
#firstDiv { position: relative; top: YYYpx; height: XXXpx; }
#secondDiv { position: relative; top: -XXXpx; height: YYYpx; }
```

Where XXX and YYY are the heights of firstDiv and secondDiv respectively. This will work with trailing elements, unlike the top answer.

Comment: Then what _should_ "be used to restructure the HTML" when, say, putting content before navigation for a screen reader?

Answer (score -1):

I have a much better code, made by me, it is so big, just to show both things... create a 4x4 table and vertical align more than just one cell.

It does not use any IE hack, no vertical-align:middle; at all...

It does not use for vertical centering display-table, display:table-rom; display:table-cell;

It uses the trick of a container that has two divs, one hidden (position is not the correct but makes parent have the correct variable size), one visible just after the hidden but with top:-50%; so it is mover to correct position.

See div classes that make the trick:
 BloqueTipoContenedor
   BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado
     BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto
     BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible

Please sorry for using Spanish on classes names (it is because i speak spanish and this is so tricky that if i use English i get lost).

The full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<title>Vertical Centering in CSS2 - Example (IE, FF & Chrome tested) - This is so tricky!!!</title>
<style type="text/css">
 html,body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoTabla{
  display:table;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoFila_AltoAjustadoAlContenido{
  display:table-row;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:auto;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoFila_AltoRestante{
  display:table-row;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido{
  display:table-cell;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:auto;height:auto;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAncho{
  display:table-cell;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:auto;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAlto{
  display:table-cell;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:auto;height:100%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAnchoAlto{
  display:table-cell;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoContenedor{
  display:block;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado{
  display:block;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:auto;position:relative;top:50%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto{
  display:block;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:auto;visibility:hidden;position:relative;top:50%;
 }
 div.BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible{
  display:block;margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:auto;visibility:visible;position:absolute;top:-50%;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Vertical Centering in CSS2 - Example<br />(IE, FF & Chrome tested)<br />This is so tricky!!!</h1>
<div class="BloqueTipoTabla" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 25px;width:75%;height:66%;border:1px solid blue;">
 <div class="BloqueTipoFila_AltoAjustadoAlContenido">
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [1,1]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [1,2]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAncho">
   [1,3]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [1,4]
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="BloqueTipoFila_AltoAjustadoAlContenido">
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [2,1]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [2,2]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAncho">
   [2,3]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [2,4]
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="BloqueTipoFila_AltoRestante">
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAlto">
   <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor" style="border:1px solid lime;">
    <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado" style="border:1px dotted red;">
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto">
     The cell [3,1]
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     Now&nbsp;is&nbsp;the&nbsp;highest&nbsp;one
     </div>
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible" style="border:1px dotted blue;">
     The cell [3,1]
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     *&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*
     <br />
     Now&nbsp;is&nbsp;the&nbsp;highest&nbsp;one
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAlto">
   <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor" style="border:1px solid lime;">
    <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado" style="border:1px dotted red;">
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto">
      This&nbsp;is<br />cell&nbsp;[3,2]
     </div>
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible" style="border:1px dotted blue;">
      This&nbsp;is<br />cell&nbsp;[3,2]
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAnchoAlto">
   <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor" style="border:1px solid lime;">
    <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado" style="border:1px dotted red;">
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto">
      This is cell [3,3]
      <br/>
      It is duplicated on source to make the trick to know its variable height
      <br />
      First copy is hidden and second copy is visible
      <br/>
      Other cells of this row are not correctly aligned only on IE!!!
     </div>
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible" style="border:1px dotted blue;">
      This is cell [3,3]
      <br/>
      It is duplicated on source to make the trick to know its variable height
      <br />
      First copy is hidden and second copy is visible
      <br/>
      Other cells of this row are not correctly aligned only on IE!!!
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAlto">
   <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor" style="border:1px solid lime;">
    <div class="BloqueTipoContenedor_VerticalmenteCentrado" style="border:1px dotted red;">
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Oculto">
      This&nbsp;other is<br />the cell&nbsp;[3,4]
     </div>
     <div class="BloqueTipoContenido_VerticalmenteCentrado_Visible" style="border:1px dotted blue;">
      This&nbsp;other is<br />the cell&nbsp;[3,4]
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="BloqueTipoFila_AltoAjustadoAlContenido">
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [4,1]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [4,2]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_RestanteAncho">
   [4,3]
  </div>
  <div class="BloqueTipoCelda_AjustadoAlContenido">
   [4,4]
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Little late to the party, but you can also do this:

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">

<div class="bottom" style="height: 250px; width: 500px; background: red; margin-top: 250px;"></div>

<div class="top" style="height: 250px; width: 500px; background: blue; margin-top: -500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Or set an absolute position to the element and work off the margins by declaring them from the edge of the page rather than the edge of the object. Use % as its more suitable for other screen sizes ect. This is how i overcame the issue...Thanks, hope its what your looking for...

Answer (score -3):

For CSS Only solution
1. Either height of wrapper should be fixed or
2. height of second div should be fixed

Comment: This does nothing to actually answer the question being asked.  It's nothing more than a comment hinting at a possible solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
.move-wrap {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; // prevent some responsive bugs
    width: 100%; // set a width if u like
    /* TODO: js-fallback IE7 if u like ms */
}

.move-down {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

.move-up {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Comment: This solution was already posted 3 years before yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12069537/1652962

Answer (score -4):

It is easy with css, just use `display:block` and `z-index` property

Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            header
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper
{
    [...]
}

.header
{
    [...]
    z-index:9001;
    display:block;
    [...]
}

.content
{
    [...]
    z-index:9000;
    [...]
}
```

Edit: It is good to set some `background-color` to the `div-s` to see things properly.

Answer (score -4):

I have a simple way to do this.

```
<!--  HTML  -->

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="sm-hide">This content hides when at your layouts chosen breaking point.</div>

    <div>Content that stays in place</div>

    <div class="sm-show">This content is set to show at your layouts chosen breaking point.</div>

</div>

<!--  CSS  -->

    .sm-hide {display:block;}
    .sm-show {display:none;}

@media (max-width:598px) {
    .sm-hide {display:none;}
    .sm-show {display:block;}
}
```

Comment: Your solution may well solve the problem - but can you please explain why/how it does. There are heaps of brand newbies on S/O and they could learn a thing from your expertise. What may be an obvious solution to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and *why/how* that code answers the question.