# Firefox CSS: Given 2 divs, how can I float the *second* one to the right using static positioning?

Tags: css, firefox, html, css-float

I'm working on a [Youtube userstyle script](http://userstyles.org/styles/12154) that displays comments side by side with the video so you can watch the video and read the comments at the same time (what a marvelous idea - duh). You can see in the screenshots how far I've got. That means I only care about Firefox, and that CSS3 goes.

The problem I have is that I want to make a fully fluid layout and have the "other videos" div float to the right, while the middle div (the comments) stretches to fill the remaining space between the left div (the video played) and the right div (the "other videos").

Translated to CSS, the problem is: given divs "main", "rightnav" and "footer", in this fixed order in the document, how can I make the rightnav div float to the right, and the footer BELOW it? The best I managed to do was to absolutely position "rightnav" (right: 0), but then the footer goes below the "main" div, not below both of them. I've looked at [Use CSS to reorder DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html) already. Negative 'top' values are out, as they depend on the content of the 'main' div.

Here's the source code:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#main {
   border: 1px solid;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 410px;
}

#rightnav {
   background-color: yellow;
   opacity: 0.5;
   border: 1px dotted;
   width: 400px;
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}

#footer {
   clear: both;
}   

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="baseDiv" style="width: 100%">
  <div id="main">
  <script>for (var i=1; i<100; i++) document.write('main ');</script>
  </div>

  <div id="rightnav">
  <script>for (var i=1; i<200; i++) document.write('rightnav ');</script>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  <script>for (var i=1; i<100; i++) document.write('footer ');</script>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully it's clear what I want to achieve: the "footer" below the two divs, and the "main" div fluid.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

```
#main {
   border: 1px solid;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

#rightnav {
   background-color: yellow;
   opacity: 0.5;
   border: 1px dotted;
   width: 48%;
   float: right;
}

#footer {
   clear: both;
}
```

that'll do it

edit: if you say liquid that usually means percent based dimensions, start associating things like that in your head

Comment: Wow. I didn't say "liquid"; I said that I only wanted the main div to be fluid, i.e. expand to fill 'the remaining space between the left div (the video played) and the right div (the "other videos")'. The 'rightnav' div is 400px fixed and it doesn't make sense to make it liquid.

Comment: then your solution is the same but with a new 400px div as child element of #rightnav (the terms liquid and fluid are interchangeable)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need position: absolute; on your right hand div, nor the right: 0; positioning. Floating the div right next to another one floated left (and with the margin set as you have) they should end up at either side of the browser window with the left hand div expanding to fill the available space (apart from the 10px gap created by your margin). When you "absolutely" position an object you are effectively removing it from the normal flow of the document and it will no longer occupy any space (nor will it "push" other objects around). I suspect that simply removing the positioning from the right hand div whilst keeping clear: both;  on the footer will fix your problem. You may also need to swap the order of left and right hand divs in the source code, so that the float: right; item comes before the float: left; item. Good luck!

P.S. Has always annoyed me too that you can't watch vids and read comments at the same time on YouTube!

Comment: That was the first solution I tried, but it doesn't work: the rightnav div never climbs to the top of 'baseDiv', but stays below the 'main' div.

Comment: You also need to swap the order that the divs appear in the source code so that the left hand div comes after the right hand div. And I don't think you need the margin-right either.

Comment: How did it go in the end, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your problem, 3 column sized by percents uses floats, containing div sizes verticly to accomadate the tallest of the 3 panels, floats must appear first inline before middle panel, IE works funny with this, thinks this layout is naturaly inline, IE hack can be seen in style.

This works good for lots of stuff, other center margined elements may appear (#mid_con) and will stack, only problem is if left and right panel heights are shorter than first middle panel the second middle panel will take up the whole #tub_con in width cuz is 100% appearing stacked directly under first middle div. This can be fixed by giving a static width to (#mid_con), it will then always center and stay same size no matter if IE is centering it in the remaining space after floats or centers it to full width. if given a static width IE hack not needed, play with it and have fun. Appears that float does not remove a div completely from normal flow in IE, seems it just pushes proceeding elements to appear and conform to the left and right of the two floats,

```
    <!--BEGIN HEADER-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <title>float3col demo</title>

 <style>
  #tub_con{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border: solid #000000;
  }

  #left_nav{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  height:80px;
  width:30%;

  max-width:30%;
  border: solid #000000;
  }
  #right_nav{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  height:80px;
  width:30%;
  border: solid #000000;
  }
  #mid_cont{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:5px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height:auto;
  width:35%;
  border: solid #f86fff;
  }
  *html #mid_cont{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:5px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  border: solid #f86fff;
  }

 </style>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
<div id="tub_con">
<div id="left_nav"></div>
<div id="right_nav">
</div>
<div id="mid_cont">
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x 
</div>

<!--Test the stacking problem
      <div id="mid_cont">
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x 
</div>-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<p style="width:100px; border:solid #000000; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
</p>
</body>
```