# Reorder div without using display table

Tags: css

I need to reorder div in my mobile version, but I cannot use display:table in my parent div cause it breaks my responsive layout.
I need to switch between additional 1 and 2.

```
<div class="product-view">
 <form action> </form>
 <div class="box-additional1"></div>
 <div class="box-additional2"></div>
</div>
```

Cannot use the solution described here: [CSS layout, use CSS to reorder DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624519/css-layout-use-css-to-reorder-divs)
Should I use javascript instead?

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `display: flex;` on the parent element and using  `order` to reorder its children. See the example (and full screen example) below.

What it does:

> The CSS **order** property specifies the order used to lay out flex items
>   in their flex container. Elements are laid out in the ascending order
>   of the order value. Elements with the same order value are laid out in
>   the order in which they appear in the source code.

Read more about the `order` property at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.product-view {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box-additional1, .box-additional2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.box-additional1 {
  background: red;
}

.box-additional2 {
  background: darkRed;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  
  .box-additional1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .box-additional2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-view">
 <form action> </form>
 <div class="box-additional1"></div>
 <div class="box-additional2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, thanks. This one seems to be working. Think my problem was that my mobile version has some width 100% and that display:table-footer-group was not working

Comment: @GiacomoRiccitiello If this solved your problem, please consider it marked as solved, so other people know that this solution can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do it on an action event? If you need to do it on an action event, I recommend using JQuery.
Just use a combination of `detach` and `append`:

```
var product = $('.product-view');
var first = product.children().eq(1).detach();
var second = product.children().eq(0).detach();
product.append(second);
product.append(first);
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2vaxg8rp/

Comment: There's no need for JavaScript.

Comment: can you edit jsfiddle to make the switch only when max screen size is 640px?  instead of the button, thanks

Comment: If you want to do it on resize, I recommend using @Rory approach to the answer.