# Place one div on top of the other div using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, html, position

I have a sign in button as shown below and when I try to click that the menu opens in which I am having an ASP.Net login control which is shown below my slider and not above it.So I would like to position it on top of my slider.And between my slider and sign in button I have menu bar.

So how do I do  that?

[image]

I have followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html) on SO but did not succeed

This is my CSS:

```
#container {
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#topnavsignin {
    padding:10px 0px 12px;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:23px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:-60px;
    margin-left:120px;
}
#topnavsignin a.signin { 
    background:#88bbd4;
    padding:4px 6px 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    *background:transparent url('../images/signin-nav-bg-ie.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    *padding:4px 12px 6px;
    margin-left:420px;

 }
#signin_menu {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#ddeef6;
    position:absolute;
    width:350px;
    z-index:100;
    border:1px transparent;
    text-align:left;
    top: 24.5px; 
    right: 171px; 
    margin-top:-55px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    *margin-right: -1px;
    color:#789;
    font-size:11px;
    padding: 5px;

}
```

This is how I'm showing it:

```
<div id="container">
   <fieldset id="signin_menu">
    //Asp.Net Login Control
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

//Here goes my Navigation menu

This is my slider part

```
<div id="slider_wrap">
            <div id="wowslider-container1">
            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To position one Div over the other you use the `z-index` on the css, together with `position: absolute or relative or fixed`

Some examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

On the container that you like to be front set a bigger z-index than the containers that you like to be on back.

**Note that:** the `z-index` works only for `position: absolute, relative, or fixed`, and the divs that you like to control have this attributes. **The example that you mention try to fix order of divs with out having one of this attributes (or with out using the z-index),** so in example can not use z-index and its a tricky how to place one in front of other with out the z-index enabled.

As I see you do not have set index in one of them.

Comment: @Aristos-it worked perfectly well.Thanks for your links.Z-index is a gud idea!.:)

Answer (score 1):

On the container that you like to be front set a bigger `z-index` than the containers that you like to be on back.

Note that: the `z-index` works only with `position: absolute/relative/fixed;` on the same element. The example that you mention try to fix order of divs without having one of this properties (or without using `z-index`); it is not possible to place one element in front of other without defining `z-index` together with `position`.