# How do I change the control icons in Report Manager?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to change the control order in Report Manager? Currently, the controls look like this:

[image]

So if I wanted to move the Export button to the far right hand side, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the .css for this element is possible, but reordering the elements would be tricky with that. (Refer to: [Use CSS to reorder DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html))

MSDN provides instructions for [modifying the .css](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). And the .css even has a tag ".ToolbarExport" so you can easily set the style of this element. But reordering: not so nice. I suspect the source for this control is in a compiled binary, so not easily accessible. (Looks like it is part of the RS:ReportViewerHost control.)

If you need customization to this degree, the best answer is to write your own report manager interface.