# using css to accomplish this layout

Tags: css

I have a responsive design site that has an odd layout changed after a media query that needs me to reorder the layout of some items: Basically I have 4 sections, a, b, c, d
So A is a left column B is a right column and c and d are their own rows below (* means a new line)
* A | B
*  C
*  D
then I need to have it reordered to 4 distict rows in this order
* A
* C
* B
* D
I can use Javascript jQuery to reorder things, but would prefer to now rely on that, so I am looking for an all CSS solution, PHP solution, and finally if all is not possible Javascript/jQuery solution.

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them. you're just listing a bunch of requirements, and this is not a programmers-for-hire board.

Comment: It is also very difficult to make out precisely what you are describing, given the sparse punctuation.  Could you improve that?

Comment: And if you're going to ask this type of question here, you should, at the very least, include some sort of sketch.

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/HV4KU/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#a { background-color: #aaa; }
#b { background-color: #bbb; }
#c { background-color: #ccc; }
#d { background-color: #ddd; }

div { 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media 
  screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    div { position: absolute; }
    #a{ 
       width: 50%;
    }

    #b { 
      top: 100px;
    }

    #c {
      left: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }

    #d { 
      top: 200px;
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I think he meant the opposite (two columns for wide displays, and four rows for narrow), but that's just a small adjustment so you get a +1 from me anyway ;)

Comment: He wanted `ACBD`. Your example is `ABCD`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson is right, but that also makes it tricky to do with css alone. relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273

Comment: @JonathanSampson Updated my post to what he required, do I get your approval now? :D

Comment: @Andy He wants four rows, in the order of A, C, B, and D. Under certain conditions, he wants A and B to share the first row, followed by C and D. One other concern is that your new approach starts to require explicit heights for elements, and this creates problems of its own.