# CSS - Animate list order

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, web

Given the following list (different height):

```
<ul>
    <li>11111111</li>
    <li>2222<br>2222</li>
    <li>33333333</li>
    <li>44444444</li>
    <li>55555555</li>
    <li>66666666</li>
</ul>
```

[image: list animation]

is it possible to animate the order of the list (Figure 1), for example moving the element `<li>2222<br>2222</li>` to the bottom of the list using CSS only?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011125/changing-dom-element-order-with-css-crocodoc#answer-25462829) will help you?

Comment: are there variables within the list. ie. length of text, width of list items, number of items in list, a class toggled on and off to trigger the position change?

Comment: To swap elements in order the commen von @Huelfe works just fine, but if you want to have an animation you can't do that css only. Therefore you would use Javscript to calculate where to put the `<li>` based on it's height and move every other element relative to that one moving.

Comment: Why include a jQuery tag if this is for CSS only?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, prefer a CSS solution but JQ will do fine as an alternative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this I suppose https://jsfiddle.net/7kjznsty

```
<ul>
    <li>11111111</li>
    <li>2222
      <br>2222</li>
    <li>33333333</li>
    <li>44444444</li>
    <li>55555555</li>
    <li>66666666</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 35px;
  animation: anom2 3s ease-out infinite;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  animation: anom 3s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes anom {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(200%);
  }
}

@keyframes anom2 {
  50% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I know this is not a really good answer, It's just a concept idea for this specific case, it sounded interesting enough to try it out, but maaaayyybe you could try something like this and work something out if CSS only is a must.

The idea would be to move the content based on margins since they can be animated by CSS.

```
li{
  transition:all 1s ease;
  line-height:20px;
  }
ul:hover li.test{
  margin-bottom:-120px;
  margin-top:80px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b03eL1d9/)

Comment: Like that animation key less approach. Can it go back to its original position?