# How to change HTML divs' order with Responsive CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive version of the "Holy Grail" [CSS layout by Matthew James Taylor](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm)

So that the Mobile page should render like this:

```
left
content
right
```

I tried changing the `float` rules as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLqrW/), but I couldn't make it work. Try to change viewport size around 600 px.

Is there a way to do this without JavaScript ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Are you asking how to change the order of the DIVs with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the divs relative and change the margin-top so that it's in the right order.

Comment: But with width:100%; they just push each other to the bottom. order does not change.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hackish, but it at least gets them in the right order. It only really works if you know what height column 1 will be.

```
.holygrail .col1
{
    margin:0;
    position:static;
    width:100%; 
    margin-top: 3ex;
}

.holygrail .col3
{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
}

.holygrail .col2
{
    width:100%; 
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

(This goes inside the media query.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this some more, and found [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html) where the answers have some good discussion about what you're trying to do. (Basically, this isn't something that CSS can do reliably.) The answers also include some hacks that are better than the one I proposed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direction to achieve this

> The direction property in CSS sets the direction of of content flow
>   within a block-level element. This applies to text, inline, and
>   inline-block elements. It also sets the default alignment of text and
>   the direction that table cells flow within a table row.
>   CSS:

```
.main-content {
  direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
}
```

> The valid values are:
>
> ltr - Left to Right, the default rtl - Right to Left inherit -
>   inherits its value from the parent element

source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/