# Switch 2 divs if visitor is on a mobile device

Tags: css

**My desktop situation:**

[image]

**My mobile device situation:**

[image]

**What I want as mobile device situation:**

[image]

Are there any CSS tricks to apply in this situation?

Comment: here is link, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/css-positioning-div-above-another-div-when-not-in-that-order-in-the-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although I think this a problem test tackled with jquery. This is
>   how I would do it with CSS

```
<div class="div-one"></div>
<div class="div-two"></div>




div-one {
       height:150px;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left
       width:50%;
       background-color:red;

   }

.div-two {
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;

   }

   @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
     .div-two {
       position:absolute;
       float:none;
       display:block;
       top:0px;
       width:100%;
       height:150px;
  }
  .div-one {
    float:none;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:150px;
  }
}
```

Here's my example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hdLDe

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResolutionDependantLayout/example-one.php may help you

If you had any doubts using this link then use this code

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

  <head>

<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />

<title>softsyn.com Resolution Dependent Layout</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />

<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='css/wide.css' />

</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="main-content">Content</div>

    <div id="secondary-one">Secondary</div>

</div>

 <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bsa_it_ad {
    padding: 8px 4px 8px 12px !important;
    position: relative;
    border: 0 !important;
    background: #D6D5D5 !important;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
}
.bsa_it_ad:before, .bsa_it_ad:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #989898;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #989898;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.bsa_it_ad:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 12px;
    z-index: -2;
    background: #6C6666;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #6C6666;
}

.bsa_it_ad a {
  margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.bsa_it_ad a img {
  border: 0 !important;
    position: static !important;
}
.bsa_it_ad a:hover img {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.bsa_it_ad a:hover {
  background: none !important;
}
.bsa_it_i {
    margin: 0 15px 0 0 !important;
}
.bsa_it_t {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0 !important;
}
.bsa_it_d {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.bsa_it_p{
    display: none !important;
}
#demo-bar-ad {
    width: 416px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    font: 11px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
}
#bsap_aplink {
    position: absolute;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    bottom: 8px !important;
    right: 8px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.bsa_it_p a:hover {
    background:none !important;
}
#demo-top-bar {
    text-align: left;
    background: #e18728;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 6000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    padding: 20px 0 15px;
}
#demo-bar-inside {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#demo-top-bar:before, #demo-top-bar:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e18728;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #8F5314;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#demo-top-bar:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 12px;
    background: #6C6666;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #62390E;
}

#demo-bar-buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 236px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0;
}
#demo-bar-buttons a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
}
#demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
#demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
    color: #333;
}

#demo-bar-badge {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 302px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
#demo-bar-badge a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(/images/examples-logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
    display: none !important;
}
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){ var bsa = document.createElement('script'); bsa.type ='text/javascript'; bsa.async = true; bsa.src = '//s3.buysellads.com/ac/bsa.js'; (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa); })();
  </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-68528-29']); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga); })();
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

style.css

```
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }
    #page-wrap { margin: 40px auto; color: white;}
    #page-wrap > div { border: 1px solid #999; padding: 71px; margin-bottom: 5px;           color: black; width: 76px; }
    #main-content { background: #eee; }
    #secondary-one { background: #eee;  }
```

narrow.css

```
    body { background: #333; }
    #page-wrap { width: 548px; }
```

medium.css

```
    body { background: #666; }
    #page-wrap { width: 700px; }
    #main-content { float: right; width: 440px; height: 300px; }
    #secondary-one { float: left; width: 170px; height: 300px; }
```

wide.css

```
    body { background: #999; }
    #main-content { float: left; width: 440px; height: 300px; margin-left: 218px; }
    #secondary-one { width: 170px; height: 300px; position: absolute; left: 0;}
```