# How to reorder DRI divs in DSpace XMLUI

Tags: dspace

I need to modify it to the home's div's order, the default current DRI is

```
<div id="aspect.artifactbrowser.CommunityBrowser.div.comunity-browser" rend="primary" n="comunity-browser">...</div>
<div id="aspect.discovery.SiteRecentSubmissions.div.site-home" rend="primary repository" n="site-home">...</div>
```

And I need to be

```
<div id="aspect.discovery.SiteRecentSubmissions.div.site-home" rend="primary repository" n="site-home">
<div id="aspect.artifactbrowser.CommunityBrowser.div.comunity-browser" rend="primary" n="comunity-browser">...</div>
```

The idea is to show recent submissions first than community abbreviated links.
I could modify it via CSS but also affects the Comunity Browse option.

Germán

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just reorder those `div`s using their `id` values (as those `id` values will be different on the Homepage and on individual Communities).

There is a "[Use CSS to reorder DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/use-css-to-reorder-divs)" question which gives some good options on how to reorder HTML `div`s based on their `id` values. Personally, I'd recommend the [JQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/220335/3750035), as DSpace already embeds and uses JQuery.

So, in the end, something like this should work:

```
$('#aspect.discovery.SiteRecentSubmissions.div.site-home').insertBefore('#aspect.artifactbrowser.CommunityBrowser.div.comunity-browser');
```

I'm not sure exactly which version of DSpace (or which theme) you are using. But, assuming you are using DSpace 4.2 (latest version as of now) and the default theme (Mirage), you can place this custom Javascript into the `page-structure.xsl` file of the theme, specifically in the `<xsl:template name="buildHead">` (which builds the HTML `head` tag for every page). Here's a direct link to that area of the code for the DSpace 4.2 Mirage Theme:
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4.2/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/core/page-structure.xsl#L220

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. It looks like a more general solution than I've commented before because it remains in presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running XMLUI, you could override the template for ds:body.  See the **xsl:otherwise** block below.

```
<xsl:template match="dri:body">
    <div id="ds-body">
        <xsl:if test="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='alert'][@qualifier='message']">
            <div id="ds-system-wide-alert">
                <p>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='alert'][@qualifier='message']/node()"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Check for the custom pages -->

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($request-uri, 'page/about')">
                <div>
                    <h1>About This Repository</h1>
                    <p>To add your own content to this page, edit webapps/xmlui/themes/dri2xhtml/structural.xsl and
                        add your own content to the title, trail, and body. If you wish to add additional pages, you
                        will need to create an additional xsl:when block and match the request-uri to whatever page
                        you are adding. Currently, static pages created through altering XSL are only available
                        under the URI prefix of page/.</p>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Otherwise use default handling of body -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@n='item-related-container']"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@n='item-related-container')]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


        <xsl:copy-of select="$SFXLink"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Finally as I've wanted to move the recent submissions before anything else, I've touched the Discovery sitemap.xmap changing the order of the maps for the home, and voila!