# Change float behaviour of div elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following divs:

[image]

**html:**

```
<div class="side left">
    <span>left</span>
</div>
<div class="side right">  
    <span>right</span>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.side 
{
  height: 100px;       
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
.left{ background-color: red;}
.right{ background-color: blue;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39xn180y/

when i minimize my browser-window width they float this way:

[image]

**question:** is there a easy (css) way to make them float that way without changing the html:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use flexbox instead of float?

Comment: @NenadVracar - sure as long as i don't have to change the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox** and **Media Queries**. With flexbox you can change [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) of elements and with [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) queries you can set when to change that order. Here is [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/39xn180y/3/)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side {
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 1 400px;
}

.left{ background-color: red; text-align: center;}
.right{ background-color: blue; text-align: center;}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .left {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="start" class="side left">
    <span>left</span>
</div>
<div id="end" class="side right">
    <span>right</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would insist you to use [**CSS - Flex**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Little changs to your CSS and "HTML"(too) helps what you want to achieve.

I think this might help you:

**<kbd>[Working Demo - UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/39xn180y/2/)</kbd>**

**HTML**

```
<span class="xyzContainer">
  <div id="start" class="side left">
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div id="end" class="side right">
    <span>right</span>
  </div>
</span>
```

> **Note :** Wrapped your both `div`'s with `span` as container for both of them.

**CSS**

```
.xyzContainer
{
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.side {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  .left
  {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

> **Note :** The trick here is done by the `display:flex` that applied to container with `order:2` to `.left` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  <style>
  .side 
{
  height: 100px;       
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
 @media screen and (max-width : 480px)
  {
           #blockContainer {
                               display: -webkit-box;
                               display: -moz-box;
                               display: box;
                              -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                              -moz-box-orient: vertical;
                              box-orient: vertical;
                           }
#blockA {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
     box-ordinal-group: 2;
}
#blockB {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
                  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="blockContainer">
    <div class="side" id="blockA" style="background:red;">Block A</div>
    <div class="side" id="blockB" style="background:blue;">Block B</div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check device size and then change float css attribute
otherwise use bootstrap Greed system..

Comment: change float css attribute how? can you show me the code?

Comment: @media screen and (max-width : 480px)
                  {
                      #divid
                      {
                        float:left !important;
                      }
                  }

Comment: can you please update the fiddle? i don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box

with search I found this where is accepted answer aswell [Change order of floated divs with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710215/change-order-of-floated-divs-with-css)

"When you use flexbox you can use the order property on items to dictate which order items appear in"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display-flex` property to reverse

here is css of that

```
body{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  -webkit-flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```

and here is the fiddle of that http://jsfiddle.net/w2ph516y/