# Bootstrap 12 column Ordering

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two 12 column sections i want to change sections in mobile design,

eg. code

```
< section class="col-xs-12" >
mobile top / desktop bottom
</ section >
< section class="col-xs-12" >
mobile bottom / desktop top
</ section >
```

Anyone know how to do it, order changes.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [Change order of floated divs with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25710215/5393271)

Comment: can't duplicate, have to try with float