# how to swap div with one another in mobile view css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For clear view i have drawn three diferent images showing my status of divs in desktop, in mobile view and what i'm trying to get in mobile view.

**1. This is current status of divs in desktop view.**
[image]

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-nav">recent posts</div>
    <div id="main">articles listing</div>
</div>
```

**2. What i get after media query for mobile device** making both divs full width.
[image]

**3. And this is what i'm trying to get**
[image]

Solution i come up with are placing divs changing position in html with floating property like below.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main" style="float:right;">articles listing</div>
    <div id="left-nav" style="float:left;">recent posts</div>
</div>
```

And this works, on mobile view after clearing floats. But this is in some CMS so i wish to get it with css if possible other way around.

Problem : as i make both div of full width (in mobile with media queries) then, the **recent articles** div appears first and then **article listing** but how can i get **Articles listing** first then after **recent posts** ?

Comment: @suvroc it's a strange comment, It's just about swapping position of a div with other, Ok, `id="wrapper" => class="row"` , `id="left-nav" => class="col-md-4"` and `id="main" => class="col-md-8"` Now answer me how do you do with this ?
With bootstrap also, if you even assign for mobile grid, the divs gets on the position as it is. How do you swap below div with upper div.

Comment: Yes, of course, it won't directly answer your question (so it is not an answer), but this is only my advice. This systems is flexible and useful across different browser

Comment: BTW, I have mentioned in question that i'm working on some `CMS` platform, so it takes time to convert all those into bootstrap. and i have used bootstrap before and you might have known from my comment above. Thank you !!

Comment: @suvroc 
 
also i have updated question with more colorful images, please check once.

Comment: What browser do you use? Or for what browser do you want to write it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some options depends on what browser do your client want to use:

For older browsers, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069537/4772988) you can use table layout to reorder your divs:

```css
#wrapper   { display: table; }
#firstDiv  { display: table-footer-group; }
#secondDiv { display: table-header-group; }
```

For newer browsers you can use [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to specify order

```css
#wrapper   { display: flex; }
#firstDiv  { order: 1; }
#secondDiv { order: 2; }
```

Comment: With the `display:table` strategy, as the '#firstDiv` and `#secondDiv` were floated left or left-right. The **float must be removed** (`float:none`)  to work `table-footer-group/table-header-group`.