# Div re-order with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsiveness

Does anybody know of any examples or tutorials on how to achieve the below:

On desktop the layout will be:
[image: Desktop layout]

On mobile the layout will change to:
[image: Mobile Layout]

As you can see, I want box 2 and box 3 to re-order and swap positions on mobile

Does anybody have any tips or advice?

Comment: The easiest way to perform this task is to take a look at the frameworks who gives tools to do this quickly like the most famous one [Bootstrap, and his grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: I think a framework works if you need it, but for things like this you don't really need a complete framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use CSS to reorder DIVs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/use-css-to-reorder-divs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what browsers you need to support you could use the `flex-box`. Using a media query for screen size you could then set the `order` of the second and third boxes to switch below a certain screen width.

I've done a [pen](http://codepen.io/KBD/pen/MwLpaL) with a short example. I'd also recommend the [CSS Tricks Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which talks about how to use `flex` far better than I can.

EDIT:

The basic principle would be to set the parent element (e.g., container) to `display: flex`  ; this generates the flexbox and allows you to set different parameters for the children.

Using the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box first">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box second">
    Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="box third">
    Box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

If I set `display:flex` on `.container`, I can then set whether the content should display in a row or column, should wrap down a line, have space between or around the elements, etc. I've set the main rule to be a wrapping row using flex-flow (which is a shorthand for two other flex properties, including `flex-direction` which I need later), with space between the elements.

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

I then use a media query so when the browser is narrower than a specified width, the `flex-direction` gets changed from `row` to `column`

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .container {
    flex-direction:column
  }
 }
```

Then, in the same media query, I need to tell the elements that I want to re-order what order they should be in:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .container {
    flex-direction:column
  }
  .second{
    order: 3;
  }
  .third{
    order: 2
  }
}
```

Sometimes I've noticed that `order` needs to be defined for all the elements, so you might need to set it for the first block and keep it as `order: 1` . From the pen linked to above, it doesn't seem to be the case here, but it something to keep an eye out for in other projects.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 4):

`flexbox` can do that very easily

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.box:first-child {
  order: 1;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .box:nth-child(3) {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gpqmaR)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this I suggest to reorder your markup.

An example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="div-1">1</div>
    <div class="div-3">3</div>
    <div class="div-2">2</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.div-1,
.div-2,
.div-3 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.div-2 {
    right: 33%;
}

.div-3 {
    left: 33%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .div-1,
    .div-2,
    .div-3 {
        width: 100%;
        left: auto;
        right: auto;
    }
}
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/umq3w14p/

Alternative you could use `flexbox!`

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}
header {
 height: 100px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}
#content {
 width: 290px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
 width: 294px; /* Account for margins + border values */
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
 width: 270px;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 float: left;
}
footer {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
 
 #pagewrap {
  width: 94%;
 }
 #content {
  width: 41%;
  padding: 1% 4%;
 }
 #middle {
  width: 41%;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  float: right;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  clear: both;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }

 
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 #content {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }
 
 #middle {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 
 #sidebar {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
 }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 
 #sidebar {
  display: none;
 }

}


#content {
 background: #f8f8f8;
}
#sidebar {
 background: #f0efef;
}
#content, #middle, #sidebar {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pagewrap, #content, #middle, #sidebar {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

 
  
 <section id="content">
  <h2>1st Content Area</h2>
  <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout, complete with responsive images and jquery slideshow.</p>
 </section>
 
 <section id="middle">
  <h2>2nd Content Area</h2>
  <p>At full width all three columns will be displayed side by side. As the page is resized the third column will collapse under the first and second. At the smallest screen size all three columns will be stacked on top of one another.</p>
  
 </section>

 <aside id="sidebar">
  <h2>3rd Content Area</h2>
  <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  
  <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
 </aside>
 


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A super-simple answer without frameworks etc. You change the original lay-out by placing the third div in second place and making him float to the right. The other two divs to the left. Once on mobile, you just change the float.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="one">Div 1</div>
   <div id="three">Div 3</div>
   <div id="two">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#one, #two ,#three
{
    width:32%;
    margin:0.6666%;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
}

#one, #two
{
    float:left;
}
#three
{
    float:right;
}

#one{
    background:green;
}
#two
{
    background:blue;
}
#three
{
    background:red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
 {
    #one, #two, #three
    {
        width:100%;
        margin:5px 0;
        display:block;
    }

    #two
    {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qu25af6f/)**