# Display Table Cell Order Change CSS

Tags: html, css

I am building a web page layout using blocks set to display: table-cell. Everything is working fine, but I cannot flip the cells (change their order) in a row and wondering if there is such possibility or some trick what I can use to achieve this.

I need to achieve this using only CSS and display: table-cell :)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

HTML

```
<div class="dtc">
    <div>Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dtc{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.dtc > *{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Current table:

```
+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 |
+-------+-------+
```

Desired result:

```
+-------+-------+
| Item2 | Item1 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/use-css-to-reorder-divs - you can do so with flexbox / order css3 property

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use RTL for parent and LTR for children. This will flip the order .

```
.dtc { direction: rtl; }
.dtc > div { direction: ltr; }
```

Without LTR for children text will not be properly aligned.

Comment: Hahaha this is perfect!!!! I tried to use direction but only for children so it did not work! Great tip! Thanks a million! :)

Comment: Ohhw look at that!