# PHP If else sorting without repeating HTML

Tags: php

I'm searching and looking if I can minimize this code. I want to sort order if the condition is true the content come first and then the image and if false the image come first.

```
<?php if(true): ?>
 <div class="col-md-6">Text Content</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">Image</div>
<?php else: ?>
 <div class="col-md-6">Image</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">Text Content</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use a decent template engine (e.g. Smarty)

Comment: Not sure what is that? No php function that I can use? So that is the shortest code to do the sorting, right?

Comment: @Jows see my answer

Comment: A template engine will separate business logic (in your case, the sorting) from user interface (the HTML). It will make you application easier to read and maintain.

Comment: in the place of `true` show us the condition so that we can help in optimizing

Comment: Perhaps relegate to CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator`

**Solution:**

```
<?php
$flip   = true;
$text   = 'Text Content';
$image  = 'Image';
?>
<div class="col-md-6"><?php echo $flip ? $text: $image; ?></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><?php echo $flip ? $image: $text; ?></div>
```

**Result with true condition**

```
Text Content 
Image
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (I'm guessing for your `col-md-` classes) you could use [reordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="<?= $condition ? 'order-2 ' : '' ?>col-md-6">Text Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Image</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$items = [
    '<div class="col-md-6">Text Content</div>',
    '<div class="col-md-6">Image</div>',
];

$reverse = true;
array_map('printf', $reverse ? array_reverse($items) : $items);
```

Or:

```
print $reverse
    ? $items[1] . $items[0]
    : $items[0] . $items[1];
```