# Position right div over the left in mobile view

Tags: html, css, position

Is it possible to stack right side div over the left sided div in mobile view with the help of CSS? The default behavior is the right sided div floats under the left sided div.

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #F48024;
    width:576px;
    height: 324px;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #EFF0F1;
    width:576px;
    height: 324px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Trying to achieve 3rd layout of this diagram.

[image]

Comment: Have you searched media-query?. you can reposition that div as you want using media-query. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/swapping-the-locations-of-two-s-in-a-media-query/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reorder my divs with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-with-css)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this by using flex box! Change Your css to this:

```
.main{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    background: #F48024;
    width:576px;
    height: 324px;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    background: #EFF0F1;
    width:576px;
    height: 324px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1152px){
  .main {
      justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .left {
      order:2;
  }

  .right {
      order:1;
  }
}
```

order property determines which element stacks first. You can read more about flex box here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can also achieve the desired effect with css `grid` layouts, as described  [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), but browser support is a bigger issue with grid

Comment: Hi @dshukertjr thanks for reply but your code initially sets the grey div to the left whereas it should be in right in desktop view.

Comment: Right. You need to user media queries to apply different css at different screen sizes. Let me edit my answer right now

Comment: Great! However, won't work in <IE11 but good solution for re-ordering.

Answer (score 11):

This may serve as a quick fix:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

You may have to use other `flex` related css props too to align and justify the content with in the `div` props like `justify-content` and `align-items`.

But if you have many `div` elements, all of them will be reversed.

```
div-n
...
div-2
div-1
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, nice solution (except <IE11 compatibility) for reversing multiple elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 200px) {
  .div {
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this using media query:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .left {
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .right {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, however your code wrapping divs in desktop view, it should not.

Comment: @KunJ, you can modify `media-query` as per your need. Tell me if modifying media-queries works for you. This is a most simple solution without using next-gen things like `flex` or `grids`

Comment: Won't work with variable content inside the div. For all that, thanks for your effort.

Comment: This only allows for fixed content. If you have variable content this is not a viable solution. Also, does not cater for multiple screen resolutions when entering from a different device. Using CSS flex option allows for it all to be fluid and dynamic.