# How to change two Div placement via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `html code`

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">I'm working Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2" >I'm working Child 2</div>
  <div class="child3" >I'm working Child 3</div>
</div>
<div class="another">
 <div class="child111">I'm working Child 111</div>
</div>
```

now I want to show `Child111` before `Child2` but after `Child1` via CSS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reorder my divs using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-using-only-css)

Comment: what do you mean with before? higher on the page or above the other div?

Comment: @JamesBurgess sir this not same like your mentioned Answer please look at the update Question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by using Flexbox and setting `flex-direction: column-reverse;` on the parent container. It will reverse the order of its children.

Read more about [Flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">I'm working Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">I'm working Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid and grid-template-areas where you can custom place the order or column with grid-area. grid-area gives you a visual representation of how the rows should appear and allows you to name the rows for better readability:

```
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "first-row"
      "second-row"
  ;
}

.child1 {
  grid-area: first-row;
}

.child2 {
  grid-area: second-row;
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Answer (score 0):

And yet another possibility:

```
.main>div{ float: left;}
```

or

```
.main>div{ float: right;}
```