# Why Does CSS Only Apply to Certain Screen Sizes?

Tags: css

I'm using the following CSS to reorder two divs:

```
#flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.ld-login-modal-login { order: 2; }
.ld-login-modal-register { order: 1; }
```

(Source: [How can I reorder my divs using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-using-only-css))

I'm not using it within any kind of media query.

It works great, but only on some screens. I'm using Safari in Responsive Design Mode to test, and for example:

1. iPhone SE (320x568) - the divs are not reordered
2. iPhone 8 vertical (375x667) - the divs ARE reordered
3. iPhone 8 horiztonal (736x414) - the divs are not reordered
4. Using my actual iPhone 11 - the divs are not reordered

I've tried adding this the site header, to no avail:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Since there's no media query involved, I'm at a loss as to why it applies to some screen sizes and not others.

I've tried encasing the CSS in various media queries with no effect.

Comment: I amunable to reproduce this issue using the code you have given. Please could you put a runnable snippet into your question which definitely gives you the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example